# Make Javascript tooltip only display when I've specified the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I'm using a small javascript to display a question mark icon with a explanatory tooltip next to product options on our ecommerce (bigcommerce) site. As it is, the script shows the icon for every product option, whether I've specified the content or not.
The content of the tooltip is set by using the following in the description section on the page:

```
<span id="[name of option]" style="display:none">[content of tooltip]</span>
```

If the content for the tooltip is not set, it displays "Description not available yet"

Here's an example of a page where the content is set:
http://www.www-savvyboater-com.mybigcommerce.com/carver-pontoon-bimini-top-sunbrella-a9sq4893ub

And here's an example of how it looks without the content set:
http://www.www-savvyboater-com.mybigcommerce.com/carver-bimini-top-double-duck-d5457ub

What I'd like is for the question mark icon to only show for the options where I've specified content for the tooltip. I don't know enough about javascript to figure it out on my own.

Here's the script in question:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".productAttributeValue").each(function() {

    var optionLabel = $(this).siblings('div');
    var optionLabelText = optionLabel.children("label").children("span.name").text();

    if ($("img", this).length < 1) {
      $(this).siblings('div')
        .children("label")
        .children("span.name")
        .append("&nbsp;<div class='help_div' style='display: inline;'><img src='/product_images/uploaded_images/help.gif'  alt='" + optionLabelText + "'/></div>");
    }

  });

  $('.help_div').each(function() {

    var slug = slugify($("img", this).prop('alt'));
    var html = $("#" + slug).html();
    var titleq = $("img", this).prop('alt').replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9,&\s]+/ig, '');
    titleq = "<strong style='font-size: 12px'>" + titleq + "</strong><br/>"
    if (!html) html = "Description not available yet."

    $(this).qtip({
      content: titleq + html,
      position: {
        corner: {
          tooltip: 'topRight',
          target: 'bottomLeft'
        }
      },
      style: {
        tip: {
          corner: 'rightTop',
          color: '#6699CC',
          size: {
            x: 15,
            y: 9
          }
        },
        background: '#6699CC',
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        border: {
          color: '#6699CC',
        }
      }
    });

  });

  function slugify(text) {
    text = text.replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9,&\s]+/ig, '');
    text = text.replace(/-/gi, "_");
    text = text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    text = text.replace(/\s/gi, "-");
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    return text;
  }

});
```

Comment: How do you create the span that has the content? Are you generating the HTML using a server-side language?

Comment: We'll be including the spans in the description html for each product. Product info, including the description, is uploaded to the server via csv. So basically, we're generating the html with excel formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to not create the HTML for the `?` in the first place.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".productAttributeValue").each(function() {

    var optionLabel = $(this).siblings('div');
    var optionLabelText = optionLabel.children("label").children("span.name").text();
    // check that optionLabelText is not an empty string
    if ($("img", this).length < 1 && slugify(optionLabelText).trim().length) {
      $(this).siblings('div')
        .children("label")
        .children("span.name")
        .append("&nbsp;<div class='help_div' style='display: inline;'><img src='/product_images/uploaded_images/help.gif'  alt='" + optionLabelText + "'/></div>");
    }

  });

  $('.help_div').each(function() {

    var slug = slugify($("img", this).prop('alt'));
    var html = $("#" + slug).html();
    var titleq = $("img", this).prop('alt').replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9,&\s]+/ig, '');
    titleq = "<strong style='font-size: 12px'>" + titleq + "</strong><br/>"
    if (!html) html = "Description not available yet."

    $(this).qtip({
      content: titleq + html,
      position: {
        corner: {
          tooltip: 'topRight',
          target: 'bottomLeft'
        }
      },
      style: {
        tip: {
          corner: 'rightTop',
          color: '#6699CC',
          size: {
            x: 15,
            y: 9
          }
        },
        background: '#6699CC',
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        border: {
          color: '#6699CC',
        }
      }
    });

  });

  function slugify(text) {
    text = text.replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9,&\s]+/ig, '');
    text = text.replace(/-/gi, "_");
    text = text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    text = text.replace(/\s/gi, "-");
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    return text;
  }

});
```

If that is not possible then there are two ways to handle this:

1. Hide the `?` in CSS by default and then show them using javascript if data exists

   .help_div {
           display:none;
       }

And in your javascript:

```
var slug = slugify($("img", this).prop('alt'));
var html = $("#" + slug).html();
var titleq = $("img", this).prop('alt').replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9,&\s]+/ig, '');
    titleq = "<strong style='font-size: 12px'>" + titleq + "</strong><br/>"

if (html) {
    $(this).show();
}
```

2. Have the `?` visible by default but destroy them if no data is found:

In your javascript:

```
var slug = slugify($("img", this).prop('alt'));
var html = $("#" + slug).html();
var titleq = $("img", this).prop('alt').replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9,&\s]+/ig, '');
    titleq = "<strong style='font-size: 12px'>" + titleq + "</strong><br/>"

if (!html) {
    $(this).remove();
}
```

Option 1 has less chance of causing issues/being jarring but it's up to you how you would like to implement this.

Comment: Your first two ideas didn't work for me, but your last one, to remove the `?` if no data is found did work, with one exception. I had to remove the `return false;` line to remove all `?`s. With that line intact, only the first `?` on each page would be removed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. I have updated the code to remove the `return false`